# PHP : Is it possible to include a file from a sibling directory?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

Hi so in my main home directory i have 2 sub directories : **subDir_A** and **subDir_B**. in **subDir_A** there is A file called **file_a.php**.in **subDir_B** I have a file **file_b.php**. in **file_b.php** i want in include **file_a.php**. is it posiible? i am using Xampp.[image]

Comment: include_once(../subDir_A/file_A.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is.

in file_B.php : `include('../subDir_A/file_A.php');`

the `../` means you want to go up a directory.

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy to accomplish using one of 4 functions.

`include`, `include_once`, `require` or `require_once`, see the documentation for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php (I won't expand on this as it's very basic PHP functionality)

You should do your include in the following fashion.

```
# you could use any of the other keywords as well.
include __DIR__ . '/../subDir_A/file_A.php';
```

The magic constant `__DIR__` was used as it will consider the reference relative the the file it's called in. If you don't do this and just do `include '../subDir_A/file_A.php';` it might not work if you included file_B.php somewhere else as it'll be relative to the parent file that called it.

Comment: Good trick but php still weired